# Setup Spatial data in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, spatial, nettopologysuite

How do I setup NetTopologySuite in .net core 2.2?

I have  this already in startup.cs

```
  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial

In the docs above it suggests to do something like this... Do I need to put my connection string in the context class too??

Also this code does not work it doesnt recognise `UseNetTopologySuite`

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
    @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=WideWorldImporters",
    x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
```

I added the nuget package, and added some usings... resharper cant even find what it needs despite doing

```
Install-Package NetTopologySuite
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question but just to help some others, cause I run into a similar problem.

In my case it was the wrong UseNetTopologySuite installed from nugget.

It must be the package 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite for SQL Server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial
(Read Installing for other databases)